# PrestaShop- Cannot get any carriers to appear during checkout

Tags: prestashop, shopping-cart

I am using PrestaShop 1.5.6.0. I cannot get a carrier to appear for order placement ("No carrier has been made available for this selection"). I would be really grateful if someone can tell me what is wrong.

I have now spent almost 10 hours checking every menu for anything that seems even remotely like it could prevent the carrier from being available.

Under Shipping->Carriers there is a carrier that came with the installation named "First Class Mail" which is enabled. Under Shipping->Shipping I selected "First Class Mail" as the default carrier.

The country that was specified in the shipping address is enabled via Localization->Countries and the zone for the specified country is enabled in Localization->Zones. Localization->States has all stated enabled (the address is in the United States).

The product dimensions & weight are configured for the product being ordered and are within the ranges configured for "First Class Mail" carrier. Group access is checked for all groups (visitor, guest, customer) for this carrier. The zone for the destination address is checked in "Shipping Locations and Costs" for the carrier for the single range that is configured (0 to 1000 lb).

When adding a new product or editing an existing product, under Shipping, there is a drop-down list of carriers containing ALL the carriers listed under Shipping->Carriers, both enabled and disabled. There is also a button that says "Unselect All". There is no apparent indication whether a carrier is selected or not in the drop-down, so I don't know if any of them are selected. Clicking "Unselect All" does not seem to do anything and there is NO method to select a carrier (only "Unselect"). In case "Unselect All" did indeed remove all carriers for the product (with no feedback or indication that this was done), I created another product where I did not click "Unselect all".

The only shipping-related module I have enabled is "Shipping Estimate" and there does not appear to be anything in its configuration that enables/disables carriers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much probing, I can answer my own question. I hope this helps others with the same problem.

Quick answer: A single carrier was selected in the specific product's Shipping configuration. The selected carrier was disabled. When I checked the Shipping configuration there did not appear to be anything selected because the selected item was at the end of the list and was scrolled out of view. If any carriers are selected here (i.e., for the specific product), then only those carriers are available for the product. If all the selected carriers are disabled (as was my situation-- one carrier, selected but disabled), then the cart will report no carrier available.

Long answer:

I already had a suspicion that the problem was with the carriers linked to the specific product.

The user interface for selecting product-specific carriers uses a multi-selection drop-down list to show which carriers are selected. You can select from both active and disabled carriers (all carriers are in the list and the carrier's active status is not shown). If nothing is selected then all active carriers are available for this product.

I thought the list was informational (as are many list boxes)-- i.e., showing the carriers currently configured for the product (not a list to select from). I expected "Unselect all" to clear the contents of the listbox and was confused when it didn't. As I noted in my question, I didn't see how to add carriers back to the list. It seems obvious in retrospect, but I did not realize you select an item (or items) just by clicking on them, or shift-click for multiple items, then pressing Save. I probably clicked the listbox and moved using the up/down arrow keys thinking I was just looking at the list of already-selected carriers, not actually selecting one. I of course left the last item highlighted and pressed "save" because I had updated the package dimensions, and the last carrier was selected.

When I later reviewed at the product configuration, the single selected carrier was at the bottom of the list and not visible when viewing the page. So I never realized I had a carrier selected (I still thought all carriers were available since they were all in the list).

A better UI would have been one of those "double" lists (I don't know the technical term for them), where items in one list (left side) are available but not selected and items in the other list (right side) are selected. You highlight items in one list and use buttons ("Add", "Remove" arrows) to move the selected items to the other list. This way you can clearly see what is selected, and what is available but not selected. Showing the carrier's active status would be a bonus.

Answer (score 3):

For a carrier to be available for a purchase, following conditions must be meet:

1. **Carrier is enabled**, and users in the **customer's group can access it**.
2. Package size / cost AND delivery zone matches a **carrier price range** (or 'use highest')
3. Package size and weight are within **carrier package limit**.
4. If any **product has selected any carrier**, the selection must include the carrier.
5. If any **product is using advanced stock management**, the carrier must be enabled for its warehouse.

Hope this list will serve as a helpful checklist for others.
The warehouse carrier selection costed me half an hour.

Answer (score 2):

[**The solution is found on this page check it out**.](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/prestashop-troubleshooter-no-carrier-available-to-delivery-error.html)

**step 1:**
In PrestaShop admin panel and go to the ***Localization -> Countries menu***. Find the country in the list and click the “cross” sign next to it to enable it. 
 example : NIGERIA.

**step 2:** . In your PrestaShop admin panel  go to the ***Localization-> Zones  menu.*** Enable the Zones you want to sell your products to by clicking on them under the Enabled column.
Example: AFRICA (because Nigeria is a country in Africa)

**Step 3:** Now you need to configure the  carriers section. Go to the ***Shipping -> Carriers*** menu. Select the carrier that you want to edit or create new one.

**Step 4:** Click on **Shipping** **locations** **and costs** and check the correct zones you want to send products related to the carrier selected before. For example, if under ***Localization -> Countries*** you enabled an African country(Nigeria), then select "Africa" in the zones section. Click Finish.

***Now your customers can select the correct shipping method in their order.***

That's all.